# Create SOAP requst by zeep

Tags: python, django, soap, wsdl, zeep

I'm working on WSDL. I need to create SOAP request using by zeep package. So I implemented the code that

```
from zeep import Client
service = Client('https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5_1/ClientService.asmx?wsdl')
request = service.service.GetClientServices
```

But I could not move on. Because I could not login through this request and pass parameters. I want to fill following all requirement through this request. could anyone tell me that how to pass all this parameters by this request. [image]
This is HTTP headers

```
SOAPAction: "http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5_1/GetClientServices"
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
```

Comment: I'm also in the same boat.